# change the default directory of command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have two programs named `abc` in different directories (`/dir1/` and `/dir2/`). Each of these directories contains other programs. In general, I would like `dir1` to be searched for a command before `dir2`. However, in the case of `abc` I would like the version in `dir2` to be executed by default. How can I make this happen?

I tried `alias`ing via `alias abc="/dir2/abc"` however that doesn't work if the command is invoked by another program. How can I make it be the default anytime somebody attempts to invoke `abc`?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered on a different stackexchange site. Here is the solution for anyone that is interested:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228701/change-the-default-directory-of-one-specific-program-without-changing-its-path

Here is the option that works for me (quoted from the answer):

Option 1: Make an override folder on your path

If you need these programs to be called in indirect ways (like by some application started by the window manager will call g++ or python, for instance), you should edit your path. You could simply add a new folder to the beginning of your path in your ~/.bashrc:

export PATH=/home/username/.bin:$PATH
and place two symbolic links to point to the appropriate programs:

ln -s /usr/bin/python /home/username/.bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++ /home/username/.bin/g++
That way, once your ~/.bashrc is properly sourced (log out, then log back in), everything should find the right python and the right g++.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.